# Where to gain lots of studs very quickly in Lego Star Wars: The Complete Saga?

Tags: lego-star-wars

I'm trying to max-out my number of studs, what are some great places to gain loads of studs in Lego Star Wars: The Complete Saga, and what is the actual stud limit for that matter. (I already have all of the multipliers, stud magnet etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about the *best* way to get studs, but the way my son and I did it was to go to Episode V, and to the level with the Millennium Falcon. You have to have the "Poo Money" unlock, and it *really* helps to have the unlock which makes your radius to collect studs much larger. There's a path that gets outside Hoth base (just a small area, and it doesn't lead anywhere). There are two Tauntauns there. Each player (or one player with a remote in each hand) can both get onto a Tauntaun. Arrange the Tauntauns so that their tails are touching, backed up next to each other. Then just keep hitting the button, and collect each other's studs.

I did this for a half hour while I watched TV (with the Wii in a picture-in-picture) until I had enough money to buy the next stud multiplier, and then did it again, and again.

The stud limit is 4 billion.

Comment: Nice thinking of getting each others pooed studs, and minimizing the downtime.

Answer (score 0):

In the bonus section, the 5th level is Lego City, where you can get 1 million studs max. You can quickly get studs there by destroying fences.
Also, behind the swings, there are 2 blue studs, where you get 1000 studs for.
If you kill random animals, you get a bunch too.

Comment: But you don't get to keep the studs you collect inside LEGO CITY unless to take the time (forever) to collect ALL possible studs there... right?

Comment: i guess, but it won't take forever. You could use 2 players or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I did the pod race in the phantom menace with all stud mulitpliers and got a billion in just 5 rounds of the pod race. So just play the pod race 5 times with all stud mulitpliers turned on.

Answer (score -1):

To anyone looking to max their studs, I’d say to activate stud magnet to increase your radius and then; a lot of people don’t know this but you can actually COMBINE all the score multiplier cheats (2x, 4x, 6x, 8x, and 10x) and gives you a multiplier of 3840. I walk out with about 250,000,000 studs per level with it activated, so I’d definitely recommend this if your lookin for studs.